# How to set canonical links correctly

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

I have been doing a lot of reading on canonical links on MOZ and know I need to implement it on my site but I am not sure of the correct way to go about it. Let me give you an example:

I have a movie review site. I have a landing page where I show an assortment of ways of viewing movies. The URL looks like `www.moviesite.com/movies`.

Say someone clicks on a category on this page the URL will look something like: `www.moviesite.com/movies/action-movies`. I use an `.htaccess` rewrite to change the URL from `www.moviesite.com/movies.php?cat=action-movies`. The content served for the category is completely different from the parent page.

Then, say someone selects a movie from the category. The URL will now look like `www.moviesite.com/movies/action-movies/movietitle-2015`. Again the content is completely different.

So in the header of my `movies.php` page what should my canonical link look like? Should it be `<link rel="canonical" href="http://moviesite.com/movies">`, then in the category view `<link rel="canonical" href="http://moviesite.com/movies/action-movies">`? Or just the parent page URL?

I have another page with the top 100 movies which is sortable by ratings. So the URL is `www.moviesite.com/top-100`. If sorted by IMDb rating it would look like `www.moviesite.com/movies/top-100/imdb-rating`. In this case the content doesn't change, it just gets reshuffled. So am I right in thinking my canonical link should just be `<link rel="canonical" href="http://moviesite.com/top-100">` and that's it?

Comment: Why would you get the idea to use the parent page URL (i.e., `/movies`) as canonical URL for the category page?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the URLs you listed should be canonical. 
I mean the ones with SEO names.
Shuffled content is  the unique content of the exact page. Also, You can add some structure data describing each page type including search results.
Your content is very good for Google Snippets.

Canonical link is needed for some case when non-public url like "www.moviesite.com/movies.php?cat=action-movies" will become public, so Google will know that canonical page will be "www.moviesite.com/movies/action-movies" on indexing.

P.s. Also, please check that you have unique titles and descriptions of each type of page ;)